# Android One Plus Two: Failed to change locale for db

Tags: android, sqlite, oneplustwo

I am using Sqlite database in one of my Android project. It works fine in all the devices except **One Plus Two** device.

I am getting exception while trying to open the database. This is the crashlog.

```
 12-23 19:14:35.235: E/SQLiteLog(3133): (11) database corruption at line 53216 of [9491ba7d73]
12-23 19:14:35.235: E/SQLiteLog(3133): (11) statement aborts at 7: [SELECT locale FROM android_metadata UNION SELECT NULL ORDER BY locale DESC LIMIT 1] 
12-23 19:14:35.237: E/SQLiteDatabase(3133): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/databases/alcochange.sqlite'.
12-23 19:14:35.237: E/SQLiteDatabase(3133): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db '/data/data/com.mycompany.myapp/databases/myapp.sqlite' to 'en_US'.
```

Please [click here](https://gist.github.com/jsramraj/120cc3067b90a82b8d6d) to see the full crash log

I have seen other questions like that here, I have tried almost every answers, but nothing works.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384854/1051215) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19491862/1051215).

**EDIT:** The device runs on [Oxygen](https://oneplus.net/2/oxygenos) Lollipop.

Comment: The device model doesn't tell us allot, firmware, rom etc. Is way more helpful as OnePlus devices generally run lots of different configurations.

Comment: This path `/data/data/com.zanec.dryjanuary/databases/alcochange.sqlite/`may not exist. Check `context.getDatabasePath(/data/data/com.zanec.dryjanuary/databases/alcochange.sqlite/)` which return `File` type.

Comment: Do you have a line `E/SQLiteDatabase(6278): Caused by: ???` in your crashlog?

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar I've checked that, its fine. This happens only in One Plus Two mobile, its working fine in other mobiles.

Comment: @naXa yes, there is. Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: database disk image is malformed (code 11).

Comment: DId you find any solution to the specific issue?

Comment: @chossen-addict Didn't find the reason, but somehow avoided. Plz see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the reason why I am having this error, but somehow I have avoided this by doing the following.

Previously, I had a .sqlite database in the bundle and when the user open our app for the first time, I copied the .sqlite database from the bundle to the correct path.

But now, I have exported the raw queries from the .sqlite and added it with the bundle as a txt file. Now when the user opens the app for the first time, I will first create an empty .sqlite file in the path and then I read all the .sql queries from the txt file from the bundle and execute them over the .sqlite file in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change locale manually.

Open your database file with a SQLite editor such as [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl), then open `android_metadata` table. if it does not exist, create it. (you may create it with the query editor (tools>open query editor) and copy/paste the DDL code below)

```
CREATE TABLE android_metadata ( 
    locale TEXT 
);
```

for inserting the record you may copy/paste this line in the query editor:

```
INSERT INTO android_metadata VALUES ('en_us');
```

Hint: to run the query in SQLiteStudio you should push the button with [image: lightning] icon in the toolbar.